# Seeking Guidance on Multi-shot DRR Generation for Lower Extremity CT with Large Field of View

Tags: image-generation

I am currently facing a challenge in generating Digitally Reconstructed Radiographs (DRRs) for lower extremity CT scans, particularly due to the large field of view required. In traditional X-ray imaging of the lower extremity, it's common to take two or three shots by rotating the camera and then stitching these images together to cover the entire area. However, I'm unsure how to replicate this process in DRR generation.

Could someone with experience in this area guide me on the following points?

Techniques for Multi-shot DRR Generation: What are the recommended methods for taking multiple shots for a large field of view in DRR? Is there a specific technique or software that facilitates this?

Stitching Process: How do I effectively stitch these separate DRR images together? Are there any tools or algorithms specifically designed for this purpose in the context of lower extremity CT scans?

Quality Maintenance: How can I ensure that the quality of the final stitched image is maintained and that there are no distortions at the seams?
Examples and Resources: If anyone could provide examples, case studies, or reference materials where similar techniques have been successfully implemented, it would be greatly appreciated.

Any insights, tips, or guidance on this matter would be incredibly helpful. I am looking to understand both the theoretical and practical aspects of this process to apply it effectively in my work.

Thank you in advance for your time and assistance!

Best regards,

Yassin

Comment: This is probably not the place you will find answer to your query, maybe post your questions to very specific community, concerning CT scans